# UICollectionvView creates unwanted page offsets

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this `UICollectionView` that scrolls horizontally where cells are in the size of a screen,
The first cell is in the right position,but as i scroll to the next page(>>right),the next cell starts with small offset from the page(left offset). now as i continue the scrolling , this left offset is increasing . so after 3 pages,the cell starts in the middle of the screen. I couldn't figure out why i have it .

```
self.collectionView.delegate=self;
self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
self.collectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
 flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing=0;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing=0;
```

---

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
         int margins=0;
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(margins, margins, margins, margins);
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                      layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       CGSize size=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
       return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Setting in code the minimum spacing between cells is not enough . You have to change it in storyboard to be 0 , and not default 10. My problem was that i had spacing between cells and so cell started with offset from the screen.